# Saxon XSD or Schema parser in java

Tags: parsing, xsd, saxon

Is there any way we can parse Schema or XSD file using saxon?, I need to display all possible XPath for given XSD.

I found a way in org.apache.xerces but wanted to implement logic in Saxon as it supports XSLT 3.0 (we want to use same lib for XSLT related functionality as well)

thanks in advance

Comment: Saxon EE supports XSD 1.0 and 1.1 schemas I think.

Comment: See http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/schema-processing/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon-EE of course includes an XSD processor that parses schema documents. I think your question is not about the low-level process of parsing the documents, it is about the higher-level process of querying the schemas once they have been parsed.

Saxon-EE offers several ways to access the components of a compiled schema programmatically.

- You can export the compiled schema as an SCM file in XML format. This format isn't well documented but its structure corresponds very closely to the schema component model defined in the W3C specifications.
- You can access the compiled schema from XPath using extension functions such as saxon:schema() and saxon:schema - see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/schema
- You can also access the schema at the Java level: the methods are documented in the Javadoc, but they are really designed for internal use, rather than for the convenience of this kind of application.

Of course, getting access to the compiled schema doesn't by itself solve your problem of displaying all valid paths. Firstly, the set of all valid paths is in general infinite (because types can be recursive, and because of wildcards). Secondly, features such as substitution groups and types derived by extension make if challenging even when the result is finite. But in principle, the information is there: from an element name with a global declaration, you can find its type, and from its type you can find the set of valid child elements, and so on recursively.

Comment: Thank you Michael,  i am looking for a open source tool, for now i will stick with org.apache.xerces .    Different question :)  in Saxon free(home) edition  is it possible to validate if generated XSLT file is valid (XSLT 3.0). I am generating XSLT file using group of XPaths (user will configure XPaths)

Comment: @kantesh, you can compile an XSLT document using http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltCompiler.html with Saxon 9 HE, if that is what you consider checking the validity. If you want to validate against an XSD schema for XSLT 3 you need EE or Xerces.

Comment: @kantesh the Saxon-HE XSLT compiler will tell you about all static errors in your stylesheet. Note however that using a path that will never select anything (e.g. because of a spelling mistake in an element name) is not a static error, it does not make the stylesheet invalid (just useless). To detect such errors you need the schema-aware version of Saxon, that is Saxon-EE, which is not open source.

Comment: sorry for late reply, thanks a lot Michael and Martin